# Saber que fecha es hoy y cómo compararla con otra

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy haciendo una pagina web de reservar y quiero asegurar que quien haga la reserva no pueda reservar con una fecha anterior a la de hoy.

Por esto quiero comparar la fecha de hoy con otra.

```js
 var dataAra = new Date();
 var data = 2022-10-13;
    if(dataAra<=data){
        Swal.fire({
            type:'warning',
            title:"Error. Dia Incorrecte",
            text: "¡Aquest dia ja ha passat!",
        });
        return false;
    }
```

`

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Y cuál es tu pregunta? Puedes Editar de nuevo y preguntar específicamente qué problema tienes con el código que nos muestras.

Comment: `var data = 2022-10-13;` no es una asignación de fecha válida, al menos no para variables que deseas que almacenen fechas. Por otro lado, la comparación de fechas no se hace entre Objetos de Fecha (estarías comparando direcciones de memoria) sino entre los valores numéricos que ellas representan. Puedes usar el método [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) o el método `getTime()` para obtener la representación numérica de una fecha.

Comment: Yo quiero comparar si la fecha es mas anterior que hoy. No quiero comparar si son iguales.

Comment: @JoelValor si algunas de las respuestas te ayudo a resolver tu problema, no olvides marcar como aceptada ✓ para que no quede pendiente ésta tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma puedes obtener la fecha actual. La ventaja de esto es que puedes obtener la fecha en el formato que quieras (ya sea con `-` o `/`). Veamos:

##### En el formato `dd/mm/aaaa`:

```js
let fecha = new Date();
let fechaActual = String(fecha.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(fecha.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + fecha.getFullYear();

console.log(fecha);
console.log(fechaActual);
```

##### En el formato `aaaa/mm/dd`:

```js
let fecha = new Date();
let fechaActual = fecha.getFullYear() + '/' + String(fecha.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(fecha.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');

console.log(fecha);
console.log(fechaActual);
```

Ahora, si deseas comparar las fechas en el formato **`dd/mm/aaaa`**, podrías hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```js
function compararFecha(fechaComparar) {
  // Inicializamos a "fecha" como un objeto tipo "Date()".
  let fecha = new Date();
  // Transformamos a "fecha" en el formato "dd/mm/aaaa" de la fecha actual.
  let fechaActual = String(fecha.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + String(fecha.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '/' + fecha.getFullYear();
  // Comparamos si la fechaActual es igual a la fecha que recibirá como parámetro la función
  if (fechaActual === fechaComparar) {
    // Si es igual retornará esto.
    return 'La fecha es igual.';
  } else {
    // Si no es igual retornará esto.
    return 'La fecha no es igual';
  }
}

// Enviamos como parámetro a la función la fecha que queremos comparar.
console.log(compararFecha('13/10/2022'));
console.log(compararFecha('21/10/2022'));
```

O si deseas en el formato **`aaaa-mm-dd`**, sería así:

```js
function compararFecha(fechaComparar) {
  // Inicializamos a "fecha" como un objeto tipo "Date()".
  let fecha = new Date();
  // Transformamos a "fecha" en el formato "aaaa-mm-dd" de la fecha actual.
  let fechaActual = fecha.getFullYear() + '-' + String(fecha.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(fecha.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  // Comparamos si la fechaActual es igual a la fecha que recibirá como parámetro la función
  if (fechaActual === fechaComparar) {
    // Si es igual retornará esto.
    return 'La fecha es igual.';
  } else {
    // Si no es igual retornará esto.
    return 'La fecha no es igual';
  }
}

// Enviamos como parámetro a la función la fecha que queremos comparar.
console.log(compararFecha('2022-10-13'));
console.log(compararFecha('2022-10-05'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Como veo que es un tema recurrente, pero a su vez es importante para la lógica de un programa, voy a intentar explicar como se deberían (a mi entender) comparar las fechas en Javascript.
Lo primero es recordar que para trabajar con fechas, javascript nos provee de la clase `Date`, esta tiene todo lo que necesitamos para poder comparar fechas, eso sí, dependiendo del tipo de comparación utilizaremos unos métodos u otros.
Crearemos objetos fecha siempre a partir del constructor de la clase `Date`, pasándole los parámetros que necesitemos.
Para crear una fecha con el valor del momento actual, utilizaremos:

```
var ahora = new Date();
```

Pero podríamos crearla con los datos que necesitemos, simplemente pasandole los parámetros en el siguiente orden:
Año, Mes(0 para enero y 11 para diciembre), Dia, Hora, Minutos, Segundos y Milisegundos. 
De la manera siguiente:

```
var fecha1 = new Date(2022, 11, 31); // 31 de Diciembre de 2022
var fecha2 = new Date(2022, 11, 31, 2); // 31 de Diciembre de 2022 a las 2 de la madrugada.
var fecha3 = new Date(2022, 11, 31, 2, 30); // 31 de Diciembre de 2022 a las 2:30 de la madrugada.
```

Bien, una vez tenemos claro que las fechas son objetos y como se crean, los operadores de comparación habituales son:

```
>
<
>=
<=
```

Por ejemplo en tu código, si realizas el cambio siguiente debería funcionar a la perfección:

```
  var dataAra = new Date();
  // var data = 2022-10-13;
  var data = new Date(2022, 9, 13);
    if(dataAra<=data){
        Swal.fire({
            type:'warning',
            title:"Error. Dia Incorrecte",
            text: "¡Aquest dia ja ha passat!",
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Ahora bien, fíjate que en el ejemplo de los operadores para comparar fechas, no he incluido el operador `==` que por lógica serviría para comprobar la igualdad, no lo he hecho porque entonces **estaríamos comparando los objetos, no su contenido**.
Fíjate en el ejemplo siguiente y verás que aunque f1, f2, f3 y f4 tienen el mismo valor, al compararlas con el operador `==` sólo obtenemos la igualdad entre f3 y f4, porque mientras no cambiemos de nuevo su valor, ambas apuntan al mismo objeto, en este caso f1, puesto que al obtener el valor como `var f3 = f1`, javascript en lugar de asignar una nueva dirección de memoria para f3, simplemente hace que herede la de f1 y de esta forma se ahorra gastar memoria para el nuevo valor, eso sí, en el momento de que f3 tome un valor que no provenga de f1 (aunque sea la misma fecha), pasaría a ser un nuevo objeto con su nueva dirección de memoria, de manera que la igualdad ya no se produciría en la comparación `f3 == f4` .

```js
var f1 = new Date(2022, 9, 13);
var f2 = new Date(2022, 9 ,13);
if (f1 == f2) {
  console.log("f1 y f2 son Iguales");
} else {
  console.log("f1 y f2 son Diferentes");
}
var f3 = f1;
var f4 = f1;
if (f3 == f4) {
  console.log("f3 y f4 son Iguales");
} else {
  console.log("f3 y f4 son Diferentes");
}
```

Una vez entendido esto, vamos a ver como comparamos fechas para saber si una es igual a otra: 
Hay varias formas, una podría ser utilizando el método `getTime()` aunque también podríamos utilizar `valueOf()`. Ambos nos devuelven un número con el valor de los milisegundos que han pasado desde el día 1 de Enero de 1970.
De esta forma podríamos comparar dos objetos de fecha de la siguiente forma:
 `if (fecha1.getTime() == fecha2.getTime() {};`
El problema con esta comparación, es que si solo queremos comprobar la igualdad entre fechas sin tener en cuenta la hora, como estamos comparando timestamps, podría ocurrir que si alguna de las fechas estuviese en otro huso horario, la comparación no sería correcta.
En el ejemplo anterior:

```
var fecha1 = new Date(2022, 11, 31); // 31 de Diciembre de 2022
var fecha2 = new Date(2022, 11, 31, 2); // 31 de Diciembre de 2022 a las 2 de la madrugada.
var fecha3 = new Date(2022, 11, 31, 2, 30); // 31 de Diciembre de 2022 a las 2:30 de la madrugada.
```

Todas las variable son de la misma fecha, pero de horas distintas, con lo cual la comparación siempre sería false.
¿Entonces, como lo hacemos?
Vamos a utilizar el método `setHours()` para igualar las horas, este método recibe como parámetros las horas, minutos, segundos y milisegundos. Una vez igualadas las horas, entonces sí que podremos compararlas con total fiabilidad.

```js
var f1 = new Date(2022, 9, 13); // 13/10/2022 0:00h.
var f2 = new Date(2022, 9, 13, 17); // 13/10/2022 17:00h.
console.log("El valor de f1 = " + f1.getTime());
console.log("El valor de f2 = " + f2.getTime());
f1.setHours(0,0,0,0);
f2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log("El valor de f1 ahora es = " + f1.getTime());
console.log("El valor de f2 ahora es = " + f2.getTime());
if (f1.getTime() == f2.getTime()) {
  console.log ("f1 y f2 son la misma fecha");
  }
```

Particularmente, en el caso de algún proyecto en el que tenga que comparar por igualdad muchas veces fechas, lo que suelo hacer es añadirle un método a la clase Date, es este caso `Fecha()` para que haga el trabajo. Quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```js
Date.prototype.Fecha = function() {
    var fecha = this.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    var timestamp = fecha.getTime();
    return timestamp;
};

var f1 = new Date(2022, 9, 13);
var f2 = new Date(2022, 9, 13, 17);
if (f1.Fecha == f2.Fecha) {
  console.log("Las fechas son iguales");
  }
```

Con todo este "rollo" espero que haya quedado bien claro como se comparan fechas en javascript.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias a todos ya he podido resolver mi problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te puedo aconsejar es cogiendo tu código y hacer lo siguiente:

```
var dataAra = new Date();
// Aquí substituye tu variable var data = 2022-10-13;
var data = new Date(2022, 9, 13);
if(dataAra<=data){
    Swal.fire({
        type:'warning',
        title:"Error. Dia Incorrecte",
        // si este es el último elemento, no tiene que tener la coma
        text: "¡Aquest dia ja ha passat!"
    });
    return false;
}
```